# Unable to Resolve Dependencies for iCal4j in Maven

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, maven-compiler-plugin, ical4j

I'm currently facing a compilation error while working with Maven in my Java project. The issue revolves around missing dependencies related to iCal4j. Specifically, the error messages indicate that packages such as
net.fortuna.ical4j.data
net.fortuna.ical4j.model

and others do not exist.

Here's a snippet of the error messages I'm encountering:

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7g9H.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMmO0.png)

I've ensured that I've added the iCal4j dependency in my pom.xml file, and I've attempted to clean and install with the -U flag. However, the problem persists.

I would appreciate any insights into why these dependencies might not be resolving correctly and how I can address this issue.

Thank you for your time and assistance!

Notes:

As you can tell, I am a beginner, and I almost have no clue what I am doing.
This is for an assignment due the day after tomorrow, and I started it a few days ago. I know it's bad.
I have been on my computer for I don't know how many hours straight, and I can't find a solution.
I have gotten multiple different error messages; I can't find them now.

Comment: The group id is wrong. It should be `org.mnode.ical4j`, not `org.mnode` (see the [corresponding `mvnrepository.com` entry](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mnode.ical4j/ical4j/3.0.27)). --- Vesion `3.0.x` seems old. I recommend upgrading to `3.2.x`.

Comment: I am seeing that i have written org.mnode.ical4j not org.mnode

Comment: The screenshot says otherwise. Please [edit] the post and add your `pom.xml`. If possible, a [MRE] (e.g. in form of a github repository) would help tremendously.

Comment: i dont know why it keeps saying i cannot post because its not formatted but it is i apologize

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check your dependencies, for the corrent ical4j it should be:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mnode.ical4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>ical4j</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.13</version>
</dependency>
```